# Ifstream stuck on a word, creating an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, ifstream

I am writing a code that gathers data from a txt file. To get to the next interesting number, I use a do-while loop. However, the first do-while loop works perfectly, but in the second one, the ifstream myfile get stuck on the word Pmax. No idea what the cause could be. =/

Here is the interesting part of the parser (I am not using XML even though it looks a bit like it):

```
ifstream myfile; 
string comment;
const string filename = "data";
myfile.open(filename.c_str());

do{
    myfile>>comment;
} while (comment != "</probScen>");
for (int i=0;i<numberScen;i++){
    myfile>>comment;
    double prov;
    myfile>>prov;
    probScen.push_back(prov);
}

do{
    if(myfile.eof()){cout<<"EoF reached"<<endl;}
    myfile>>comment;
} while (comment != "</Pmax>");
for (int i=0;i<H;i++){
    myfile>>comment;
    double prov;
    myfile>>prov;
    Pmax.push_back(prov);
}
```

And here is the part of the txt file I want to read:

```
<probScen> scenario s - happening probability </probScen>
1 1
<Pmax> hour h - max price for this hour </Pmax>
1 5
```

The first do-while loop handles the probScen fine, but myfile in the second do-while gets stuck on Pmax, thus creating an infinite loop. To be more precise, myfile reads every single word until /probScen, then 1, 1, Pmax but then does not move on anymore. The myfile.eof() never returns true.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The only thing you will accomplish by trying to parse XML this way is a feature article on [http://thedailywtf.com](http://thedailywtf.com). You need to use a proper XML parser library to parse XML documents.

Comment: If this were happening to me (and I weren't using an XML parser), I would add debugging code to observe each word being read from `myfile`.  That would show me where things were getting stuck.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.xml_parser

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I actually used some "cout<<...<<endl;" to see what myfile reads. myfile reads all words until </probScen>, then 1 1, then reaches <Pmax> and does not move on anymore.

Comment: You might want to check `myfile.eof()` to break the infinite loop at least... `myfile.fail()` can hint you to an error with the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will occur as soon as numberScen is greater than 1 (one)!

First iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberScen; i++)
{
    myfile>>comment; // consumes 1
    double prov;
    myfile>>prov;    // consumes 1
    probScen.push_back(prov);
}
```

Second iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberScen; i++)
{
    myfile>>comment; // consumes <Pmax>
    double prov;
    myfile>>prov;    // trying to parse 'hour', but fails!
                     // from now on, fail bit is set
    probScen.push_back(prov); // stores uninitialized value
}
```

Within the following while loop, as the fail bit is set, nothing is read at all, and so comment remains at the latestly consumed ""...

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me! I was certain that numberScen was set to 1, and it actually was not. This now perfectly makes sense.